# Why doesn't str != "hello" && "goodbye" work?

Tags: c++, string, function

**I'm trying to exit the "do" function if the strings "hello" or "goodbye" are entered**, this function works for just "hello" but not "goodbye". 
Can anyone explain to me what's the problem with my function?
Also if there is a better way to do it, I'd like to see as well.
Thanks

"Hello" || "Goodbye"
"Hello", "Goodbye"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



int main()
{
    std::string str;
    do {

        std::cout << "Say Hello, sir.";
        std::cin >> str;

    } while (str != "Hello" && "Goodbye");

    std::cout << "You're rude, bro";
}
```

I expect the "do" statement to exit and continue to the cout statement after "Hello" or "Goodbye" is entered.

Comment: You should be writing `while (str != "Hello" || str != "Goodbye")`. Comparisons are always one to one.

Comment: @lilitmouton you likely need to have str != "Goodbye". Right now, your 2nd condition is just a string rather than the Boolean you want.

Comment: @AlexG: That's also a misunderstanding about how comparisons and logical operators work together.  Your version will loop forever.

Comment: @AlexG in your example, you need to use `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 7):

The condition `str != "Hello" && "Goodbye"` is effectively `(str != "Hello") && "Goodbye"`. The `&&` operator does not join multiple operands of `!=`. It is a completely separate operator.

The first operand of `&&`, `str != "Hello"`, compares `str` to `"Hello"`, which is what you want. The second operand, `"Goodbye"`, is not what you want.

When `"Goodbye"` is the operand of `&&`, it is converted to `bool`. (In detail, this string literal is first converted to a pointer to its first character and then to `bool`.) The result of converting a non-null pointer to `bool` is `true`.

So `str != "Hello" && "Goodbye"` is the same as `str != "Hello" && true`, which is the same as `str != "Hello"`.

The condition you want is `str != "Hello" && str != "Goodbye"`.

Comment: Yay!  Someone conversant in Boolean logic!

Comment: @BenVoigt Now you made me sad :'(

Comment: @Swordfish: I didn't mean to imply that you aren't, it was a contrast with the previously offered *answer*.

Comment: @BenVoigt And I was not being serious about being sad ^^

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` code is evaluating `( str != "hello" && "goodbye")`. In C++, this is equal to `( (str != "hello") && true)`. `"Goodbye"` is evaluated to true because it's a string literal, which evaluates to true because it is not a `nullptr`.

Your need to do `(str != "Hello" && str != "Goodbye")`.

Comment: _Because the string are evaluate like true bacause is defined_ I'm not sure what you're saying here. It evaluates to `true` because it's a string literal, which is a `const char*`, and pointers evaluate to true if they're not `nullptr`

Comment: Thanks Tas for the explanation. The explanation was added to my answer.

Comment: @Tas *because it's a string literal, which is a const char* – just nitpicking: The type of a string literal is array of N `const char`.

Comment: *a string literal, which evaluate to true if they're not nullptr.* – And since a string literal cannot be a `nullptr` they're always `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Close, you just need to be more explicit.

```
str != "Hello" && str != "Goodbye"
```

You have to make each str comparison separately.